# Very large Microsoft.OSTCExtensions - LinuxDiagnostic extension log

Tags: azure, azure-diagnostics

Good day all,

I have installed Microsoft.OSTCExtensions - LinuxDiagnostic - 2.3.9025 extension

and then have enabled Monitoring -> Diagnostics -> 'Basic metrics' & 'Boot diagnostics' and chosen a storage account.

I can see that I currently have > 5GB log at below location which keeps entries since more than two months ago:

/var/log/azure/Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.LinuxDiagnostic/2.3.9025/extension.log

Is it normal that the log for the metrics is stored on the Linux machine and how can I reduce it's size or store on the storage account (blob, table etc.) without filling my linux disk partition?

Many thanks,

Archie

Comment: No, the log for the metrics is stored on Azure storage account, it does not store on your Linux VM. Could you use `cd /var/log/azure/ ;du -sh *` to check what files take up so much space.

Comment: `/var/log/azure/Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.LinuxDiagnostic` save extension install log, it should not take up so much space.

Comment: I just ran into the same problem. My `extension.log` file was at around 25GB, which filled up the storage on my VM and actually caused my screen session to crash. Deleted the file and it's all okay now, but will have to keep an eye on it.

Answer (score 0):

and i fixed it one better:

- after i deleted the file, i soft-linked it to `/dev/null`:

```
> sudo su
> cd /var/log/azure/Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.LinuxDiagnostic
> rm extension.log
> ln -s /dev/null extension.log
```